# How to upload an image in base64 in mongodb using angularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am trying to upload an image in base64 to my mongodb. The image will be selected by an input type="file" by the user and when the form is all compiled the user can click the button "SAVE". I am using AngularJS and I need to setup the angular controller, the Service as well as the backend.

This is what I have rigth now:

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form" name="form">
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rooms.nome" id="nome"
    required />
      <label for="nome">Nome</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="file" ng-click="upload()">upload</button> //this is just an example
 </div>
 <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveRoom()" type="button" 
    ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Save</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
angular
    .module('roomApp')
    .controller('addRoomController', ['$scope', 'roomService', '$http', function ($scope, roomService, $http) {
$scope.saveRoom = function () {
        $scope.room = [{
            "nome": $scope.rooms.nome,
            "posti": $scope.rooms.posti,
            "indicazioni": $scope.rooms.indicazioni,
            "indirizzo": {
                "via": $scope.rooms.indirizzo.via,
                "num": $scope.rooms.indirizzo.num,
                "cap": $scope.rooms.indirizzo.cap,
                "citta": $scope.rooms.indirizzo.citta,
                "nazione": $scope.rooms.indirizzo.nazione,
                "piano": $scope.rooms.indirizzo.piano
            }
                //I think here I have to manage the file
        }];

         $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/irs/rooms/insert',
            data: $scope.room,
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data.ops[0])
            roomService.setRoom(data.ops[0]);
            location.href = "#/";

        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error checking server');
        });
    }
}]);
```

**Web Client Service:**

```
angular
    .module('roomApp')
    .factory('roomService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var rooms = [];

        return {
            checkRoom: function () {
                return rooms;
            },
            setRoom: function (room) {
                rooms.push(room);
            },
 };
}]);
```

**DAL:**

```
RoomsDal.prototype.defineModel = function(database) {
    this.Rooms = database.model('Rooms', {
        _id: {
            type: 'objectId',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            index: true
        },
        nome: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        posti: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        indicazioni: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        indirizzo : {
            via: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            num: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            cap: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            citta: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            nazione: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            piano: {
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            image: {
                data: 'buffer',
                contentType: 'string' //I am not sure about this
            }
        }
    });
};

RoomsDal.prototype.insertOrUpdate = function(id, nome, posti, indicazioni, indirizzo) {
return this.Rooms.findOneAndUpdateQ({
    _id: id
}, {
        _id: id,
        nome: nome,
        posti: posti,
        indicazioni: indicazioni,
        indirizzo: {
            via: indirizzo.via,
            num: indirizzo.num,
            cap: indirizzo.cap,
            citta: indirizzo.citta,
            nazione: indirizzo.nazione,
            piano: indirizzo.piano
        }
    //Here I have to insert the image
}, {
    upsert: true,
    'new': true
});
};
```

**Service:**

```
RoomsService.prototype.getDescriptor = function() {
return {
    insertRooms: {
        handler: this.insertRooms,
        method: 'post',
        path: '/irs/rooms/insert'
    }

 };
};


RoomsService.prototype.insertRooms = function(request, response, next) {
var Q = require('q');

Q.all(RoomsService.RoomsDal.insert(request.body))
    .then(function(results){
        response.send(results)
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        RoomsService.logger.error('Error while getting detail of service container. Error: ' + error.message);
        RoomsService.prototype.sendGenericErrorResponse(response);
        next();
    });
};
```

With this informations how can I handle the image upload? Thanks for the help

Comment: [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) may help you with file upload to NodeJS.

Comment: It is more efficient to upload images as binary files and convert it to base64 on the server side. Using base64 in a POST request adds 33% more overhead.